# Почему массив в динамической области памяти инициализируется как-то странно?

Tags: c#

Почему массив в динамической области памяти инициализируется как-то странно...

```
internal sealed class Core
    {
        private static unsafe void Main()
        {
            const int bufferSize = 100;

            IntPtr memoryPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
            Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(memoryPointer.ToPointer(), bufferSize);

            byte index = 0;
            foreach (ref int value in buffer)
                value = index++;

            foreach (ref readonly int value in buffer)
                Console.Write($"{value}, ");

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memoryPointer);
        }
    }
```

Выходные данные: 103, 111, 0, 98, 0, 0, 78...
А должно быть: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

Comment: `int` != `byte`

Comment: пробовал и int, не помогает.

Comment: Сделайте `byte value` в обоих циклах

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы используете `Span<byte>`, то и далее нужно использовать тип `byte`.
В обоих циклах меняем тип переменной `value`:

```
foreach (ref byte value in buffer)
    value = index++;

foreach (ref readonly byte value in buffer)
    Console.Write($"{value}, ");
```

---

Если нужно работать с типом `int`, то и спан нужно создавать с этим типом:

```
var buffer = new Span<int>(memoryPointer.ToPointer(), bufferSize / sizeof(int));
```

Так как `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` выделяет количество памяти в байтах, нужно для спана длину пересчитать в интах.